# Sorting between start and end times for a set of projects

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation

I need a way to nest projects that I am working on. The list is so large that it is impossible to do it by hand. I am attaching an example of what I am looking to do.

[My starting data is what you see on the left hand side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZQz.png)

My goal is to be able to nest project tasks into project parts into the project number itself. Tasks will have start and end date and will be tied to a part, so the part start and end date should be the smallest start date and largest end date. This follows true for overall project start and end, the smallest beginning time and largest ending time should be the start and end for the overall project.

I cannot find a good way to do this and was wondering if there were any suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the bad way you have found? It would help us to know so we don't suggest it for nothing

Comment: I tried using min() and max() on the start dates and sorting by project number but it doesn't seem to stick with the data organization.

Comment: @KeithMiller,, what U are getting in J2:M11 and in Q2:S5 are Filtering Data for Start and End Dates,, can be performed using INDEX MATCH also,,, confirm through comments,, if is correct what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 0):

You can compute start and end dates (columns L, M, R and S) with MINIFS and MAXIFS, e. g.

```
L3: =MINIFS(E:E;B:B;J3;C:C;K3)
```

If your Excel version has dynamic array formulas (AFAIK Office 365 only), you get the lists for columns J, K and Q with UNIQUE, e. g.

```
J3: =UNIQUE(B3:C44)
```